# Cannot make egit work with a server via ssh

Tags: eclipse, git

Running the Mars version of Eclipse on Windows 10.  I'm trying to clone a repository with this URL (domain name replaced with example.com):

ssh://git@git.example.com/opt/git/dnsconfig.git

Initially I had a lot of trouble trying to connect, because Eclipse did not have the server fingerprint in known_hosts, and had no way to accept the unknown fingerprint.  I eventually figured out a way around that (copy the line from a Linux server's known_hosts file to the eclipse known_hosts on Windows).  The public key matching the private key in eclipse has been added to the authorized_keys file on the server.

Now that I have solved the fingerprint problem, when I try the clone, I get to the Branch Selection screen and this is the error message at the top:

> ssh://git@git.example.com/opt/git/dnsconfig.git: not found.:
>   ssh://git@git.example.com/opt/git/dnsconfig.git: not found.

If I go to a Linux machine and type the following command (this host is also set up with an ssh key in authorized_keys on the server), it works perfectly:

> git clone ssh://git@git.example.com/opt/git/dnsconfig.git

I set up the server using this as a guide:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

This is probably user error ... can anyone help me figure out what I've done wrong?

Comment: Running sshd in debug mode on another port, and changing the port in eclipse, got me this debug info:

http://apaste.info/HHY

It looks like eclipse is closing the ssh connection after the server sends its keys (SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent), instead of sending a key back.

Comment: Further info:  The same thing happened on the sshd debug (alternate port) even when I typed the git user's password and checked the box to save it in the secure store.  I don't want to use passwords, but even if I did, that's not working either.

Comment: In your log from sshd you seem to use putty as a client. AFAIK putty will not read your ssh configuration, so it will most likely not use any keys unless you specifically configure it... I would donwload [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and troubleshoot it from command line. Another idea is JGit reads SSH .config file. Perhaps you have some conflicting config for that host?

Comment: I can promise you that I did not (directly) use putty for that connection.  I was clicking buttons in Eclipse to clone a git repo.

Comment: I tried with msysgit (which I already had installed).  That also didn't work.  In the Git Bash included with msysgit, I successfully made a plain ssh connection (without git) using the ssh key I already had in c:\users\username\.ssh from my attempts with eclipse.  Here's the log from Git Bash:  http://apaste.info/lGo

Answer (score 0):

After I tried msysgit, the note from Michał Grzejszcza talking about Putty led me to try one more thing.

I *do* use putty quite frequently, and I have a key that I keep loaded in pageant, which I use to log into personal accounts on several servers.

I was not using that personal key for eclipse, I wanted to use a completely separate key for git.

When I added the matching public key for my personal key to the git user's authorized_keys file on the git server, suddenly both eclipse and msysgit were working fine, which means that both of them are tied into putty.  This was a little surprising for msysgit, since the info I have on msysgit says that it comes with and uses openssh.